# laravel - index.php can't require specific files inside a public_html folder

Tags: php, laravel

I want to deploy my laravel application on a shared webhost, I have follow this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6g8G3YQtQt4 and its works perfectly, only if I put the `public` folder in `public_html`, but I want to put in another folder in public_html, (to be more exactly, in: `public_html/myapp`, but I get this error

```
[15-Apr-2022 15:19:32 UTC] PHP Warning:  require(/home/killestone/public_html/myapp/../web/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/killestone/public_html/myapp/index.php on line 24
[15-Apr-2022 15:19:32 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/home/killestone/public_html/myapp/../web/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/share/pear') in /home/killestone/public_html/myapp/index.php on line 24
```

this is my `index.php` inside `public_html/myapp`

The rest of my laravel application is on `/home/killestone/web/`

```
<?php

/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *
 * @package  Laravel
 * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylor@laravel.com>
 */

define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register The Auto Loader
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader for
| our application. We just need to utilize it! We'll simply require it
| into the script here so that we don't have to worry about manual
| loading any of our classes later on. It feels great to relax.
|
*/

require __DIR__.'/../web/vendor/autoload.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Turn On The Lights
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| We need to illuminate PHP development, so let us turn on the lights.
| This bootstraps the framework and gets it ready for use, then it
| will load up this application so that we can run it and send
| the responses back to the browser and delight our users.
|
*/

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../web/bootstrap/app.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Run The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Once we have the application, we can handle the incoming request
| through the kernel, and send the associated response back to
| the client's browser allowing them to enjoy the creative
| and wonderful application we have prepared for them.
|
*/

$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Comment: Try removing ../

Comment: can you clarify - are the files in `/home/killestone/public_html/web` (as stated in the title) - or in ` /home/killestone/web/` (as stated in the question)?

Comment: @bdecaf All the laravel files are in ``/home/killestone/web`` and in the ``/public_html/myapp/`` are the files from the ``public laravel folder`` (eg: index.php, .htaccess, web.config, etc)

Comment: @Freezy php is absolutely pedantic about it. The warning mentions that the app is in `/home/killestone/public_html/myapp/`  - if it's there you need `/../../web` (2x `..`). if it's in `/public_html/myapp/` you better not use the `__DIR__.` construct.

Comment: Yea, I don't know why, I've put before 2x ``/../../`` and it didn't work, but now it does. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your `public` directory lives inside sub-folder inside the `public_html`
so you need to add an extra `../` because your public app lives in

```
public_html/myapp
```

so the first `../` will point to the `public_html` dir and the second `../` will point you to the `home` directory
like this

```php
<?php

/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *
 * @package  Laravel
 * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylor@laravel.com>
 */

define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register The Auto Loader
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader for
| our application. We just need to utilize it! We'll simply require it
| into the script here so that we don't have to worry about manual
| loading any of our classes later on. It feels great to relax.
|
*/

require __DIR__.'/../../web/vendor/autoload.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Turn On The Lights
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| We need to illuminate PHP development, so let us turn on the lights.
| This bootstraps the framework and gets it ready for use, then it
| will load up this application so that we can run it and send
| the responses back to the browser and delight our users.
|
*/

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../../web/bootstrap/app.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Run The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Once we have the application, we can handle the incoming request
| through the kernel, and send the associated response back to
| the client's browser allowing them to enjoy the creative
| and wonderful application we have prepared for them.
|
*/

$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```